# Why doesn't MDRaisedButton work on Android?

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

I successfully converted the Python file into APK, but the button doesn't work. However, it works on my computer, but  there is no response when I'm pressing the button.

Code:

```
class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def on_start(self):
        os.environ['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = certifi.where()
        UrlRequest('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php', on_success=self.success, on_failure=self.failure, on_error=self.error)
    def success(self, urlrequest, result):
        ingredient_list = self.root.ids['home'].ids['ingredient_list']
        print(result)
        self.youtube = result['meals'][0]['strYoutube']
        self.name = result['meals'][0]['strMeal']
        self.category = result['meals'][0]['strCategory']
        self.area = result['meals'][0]['strArea']
        self.image = result['meals'][0]['strMealThumb']
        self.url = result['meals'][0]['strSource']
        for i in range(1,21):
            if result['meals'][0][f'strIngredient{i}'] != '':
                l = Label(text=result['meals'][0][f'strIngredient{i}'],color=(0,0,0,1))
                ingredient_list.add_widget(l)
    def view(self):
        if self.url != '' and self.youtube == '':
            Snackbar(
                text=self.url,
                size_hint_x=2
            ).show()
        if self.youtube != '' and self.url == '':
            Snackbar(
                text=self.youtube,
                size_hint_x=2
            ).show()
        if self.youtube != '' and self.url != '':
            Snackbar(
                text=self.youtube,
                size_hint_x=2
            ).show()
        if self.youtube == '' and self.url == '':
            Snackbar(text='Url is not available').show()

MainApp().run()
```

KV file

```
ScreenManager:
HomeScreen:
    id:home
    name:'home'

<HomeScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        MDRaisedButton:
            pos_hint:{'top':.27,'right':.65}
            size_hint:.3,.05
            text:'View'
            on_press: app.view()
```

Comment: Are you using the same version of kivy and kivymd in both your pc and in buildozer.spec file? Might be one of the reason for that. Try using latest version of both in buildozer.spec file